# Have him do or does it

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct and why? " Let's have him do it. " Or " Let's have him does it. "
Since it's " him " I think it should be does but I'm not sure..

Comment: As user5768790 indicates, the complement there (**do it**) is an infinitive.  He is not actually doing it.  We *intend* to have him do it. His action is not yet taking place in time, so it does not need a tense.  We want him **to do** it.  We can also use participle: *We want him **doing** it, not her.  We want him **to do** it, not her.*

Answer (score 2):

***To have + somebody + do something (infinitive without to) means 'to get somebody to do something':***

> - Bruno had Icarus check last year's figures. Bruno got Icarus to check last year's figures.
> - They would have Icarus do all the work himself, if they could. They would let Icarus do all the work himself, if they could.
> - I have the gardener take care of everything. The gardener takes care of everything, at my request.
> - Horatio had the test monkeys drive him around the city. Horatio got the test monkeys to drive him around the city.

From gymglish.com

Answer (score 1):

Careful here not to confuse your verbs:
 - to have someone do sthg - this construction means that we decline the "to have" part and not the "do" part - this remains the same - compare these examples:

- let's have him do it
- she has him do it
- I have him do it
- he had her do it